# How to specify tranform_param in deploy.prototxt

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

While building deploy.prototxt from a train_val prototxt file in caffe, how to specify the transform params in the deploy file.
For instance, I have the following data layer in `train_val.prototxt`:

```
    layer 
{
        name: "data"
        type: "Data"
        include {
          phase: TRAIN
       }
      data_param 
{
        source: "/path/to/train_lmdb"
        batch_size: 32
        backend: LMDB
      }
      transform_param {
        crop_size: 224
        mean_value: 103.939
        mean_value: 116.779
        mean_value: 123.68
        mirror: true
      }
    }
```

I understand I have to delete this layer from deploy.prototxt but then how do I specify those mean value? Or the crop size ?

In my case the deploy file would look like

```
name: "VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers"
input: "data"
input_dim: 10
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 224
input_dim: 224
```

But where do I specify the transform_param?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your net, it is your responsibility to transform your inputs in the same way you did during training

Comment: Yes but can't we transform our inputs by having a transform layer for in deploy.prototxt like we do in train_val.prototxt?

Comment: @Valyrian AFAIK transform is not a layer